# Encryption of Google's Android apps

Tags: encryption, android, google, gmail

Does Google use network encryption on it's Android apps like Gmail, Drive, Google Play, Docs, and others when doing authentication/data transfer? What type of encryption is it? Is it secure?

I have tried searching Google's help site about this and did not find a good answer. Can you provide me with some resources about the topic?

Comment: Can you give some context?  Encryption of what exactly?  Communication between the apps and the servers?  Encryption on the device itself?

Comment: yes connection between the apps and the servers , and what exactly included (authentication , file transit , metadata )

Answer (score 1):

[image: packet capture of android phone communicating with Google's server]

Above is a packet capture of communication between my phone and Google's server(74.125.68.19). Apparently, TLS is used to protect data in transit. TLS is also used for your browser's connection to a HTTPS website so the security is comparable.

If transmitted over cellular networks, there is a second layer of encryption between your phone and your provider. The algorithm used could be A5/KASUMI depending on the network.

Answer (score 1):

Google [encrypts everywhere](https://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal_6.html):

> Security is a top priority for Google. We invest a lot in making sure
>   that our services use industry-leading security, like strong HTTPS
>   encryption by default. That means that people using Search, Gmail and
>   Drive, for example, automatically have a secure connection to Google.

Its apps use HTTPS to communicate with its APIs.